# Changing domain alias and send mail from on a Blackberry

Tags: email-server, g-suite, blackberry, mobile-devices

I have domain1.com configured in Google Apps for the email server. Recently the company changed its name to domain2.com, and that new domain was added as an alias for domain1.com in Google Apps.

If the emails are sent from the web interface, its really easy to change the "send email from" to use the alias all the time. The problem is that all the employees use BlackBerry devices. Is there a way to configure those devices to send the emails from @domain2.com by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, no. There is unfortunately no way to change the primary domain on a Google Apps account. If you have a paid Premium account, perhaps there is a way you can do this through your support contact, though.

Comment: i don't to change the primary account, just a way to use the alias domain as the "sent from" in blackberry mobile devices.

Comment: @andufo - right, which is what they refer to as the "primary domain".

Comment: oh sorry, didn't know. anyways, i've searched the last 25 minutes for a solution without any answers... i think they'll have to go with the paid version. they are not accepting free accounts anymore in google apps.